How to get the source element in Angular
I want to get the source element such that I can either pass it to a function or use it in an expression in an *ngIf.  Something like this:
<span *ngIf="someFunction(refToThisSpanElement)"></span>

This is also an element that is generated in an ngFor.  I'd prefer to not use a ViewChildren/Querylist if possible.

Yes, you can work with Template Reference Variable.
<span #refSpan>{{ value }}</span>

<span *ngIf="someFunction(refSpan)"></span>

someFunction(spanElement: HTMLSpanElement) {
  console.log(spanElement);

  // Implementation
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

As I said, there are a list of these generated in a *ngFor so using a template variable won't work.  Obviously in that case you would need to use the ViewChildren decorator and go through that mess which I'd like to avoid.  If I had the ability to simply get a reference to the DOM element I could then check the properties I need.
